# Notions of Duality in Vedas/Puranas

Tags: vedas, philosophy, dvaita

This is my first post on the Hinduism community and I do not have prior knowledge of the rules of the community, so I hope my question is in the right place. I have found that the stories of lore sometimes help solve or at least tackle the same philosophical questions that we face in life. This motivated me to ask a question here about a question I'm currently trying to resolve for myself.

I have been struggling with a philosophical question for a while which deals with choosing between two dual approaches. To put it simple terms, when trying to solve a problem, there is a top-down approach and there is a bottom-up approach. Both these approaches are supposed to solve the same problem but they take opposing views and actions. In a way, these are dual to each other. Neither is better than the other but sometimes one is preferable over the other. Most times its difficult to say which one is preferable. But the deeper idea here is that for every approach there is a dual approach. The highs and lows of life, spirituality vs. materialism, and many other examples show us that duality is indeed a significant concept.

Coming back to my question about dual problem solving approaches, I believe that investing in a harmonious alliance of both approaches is well worth the effort when solving some problems, but it is not always clear how one could go about doing this. And this brings up to why I am posting here. I am looking for stories from the Vedas or Puranas which deal with duality as a source of motivation for answering my own question. For example, Guru Shukra and Guru Bṛhaspati are sages on opposite sides but their objectives are ultimately the dissemination of knowledge (Please correct me if i have this wrong.) I am looking for stories like this not only hoping that it would help me with my own question, but also because they are interesting on their own. Can someone point me to stories like this or sources where i can find them? Thanks.

Comment: This question is very general and wide. It would be better to be specific.  In this site we seek answers for specific questions. the duality of problem solving you have illustrated is not very clear.  Please try to rephrase your question specifically. Is it about duality of God - the duality of say Shiva and Shakti, duality of Shiva / Vishnu or duality of the Hindu Schools of Philosophy like Advita of Adi Shankara and Visishtadvita of Ramunja charya and / or Dvaita of Madhavcharya., etc.

Comment: @SureshRamaswamy I am interested in general ways that duality comes up in the scriptures. I am trying to look for different aspects of the stories which point toward a dual structure. I am sorry if my question comes across as abstract, but I am essentially only looking for instances where the concept of duality arises.